# Printing GNU-screen results in a file

Tags: shell, weka, gnu-screen

I am trying to use the screen command on linux. I need to print the stdout that I get in a normall shell command to a separate file after a detached session is done. How can I do so?

In particular, I am trying to run Weka experiments in screen and I need the results in a seperate file. For instance, the results of the following?

```
screen java weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes -t data.arff -x 10
```

When I am not using screen I simply get the results using:

```
java weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes -t data.arff -x 10 > file.output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always simply run the command not directly, but via shell:

```
screen bash -c "java weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes -t data.arff -x 10 > file.output"
```

Alternatively, one can use the built-in screen session logging. Unfortunately, `screen` isn't particularly smart and somewhat buggy, thus one has to resort to trickery to allow setting a custom output file. The best way I could come up with is as follows.

Create special configuration file, e.g. `~/.screenrc-redir`. Content is just single line:

```
logfile $OUTFILE
```

Now, in `bash` prompt, redirection could be accomplished like this:

```
OUTFILE=file.output screen -L -c ~/.screenrc-redir <your-command>
```

What it does, is start screen with logging redirection, and send the output of the session to the file specified by the environment variable name.

Theoretically, the `-L` on command line could be replaced with the `log on` in the configuration file. But that for whatever reason doesn't work. Probably a bug in the `screen`.